# Delete multiple files through aws cli not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have to delete the several .tar files on my s3 bucket. I run the command for doing this through aws cli but getting the error i.e

> Error parsing parameter '--delete': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
>   '{Objects:[{Key:2019-03-27T160001Z.tar},{Key:2019-03-27T170001Z.tar}]}'

```
My aws version is : aws-cli/1.16.136 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.126
```

My command is:

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket mybucket --delete '{"Objects":[{"Key":"2019-03-27T160001Z.tar"},{"Key":"2019-03-27T170001Z.tar"}]}'
```

Is there anyone who can guide me on where I am doing mistake. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You command worked fine for me. As per [delete-objects — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-objects.html), you can also use:

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket mybucket --delete 'Objects=[{Key=2019-03-27T160001Z.tar},{Key=2019-03-27T170001Z.tar}]'
```

Comment: Using your command I get the error i.e `Error parsing parameter '--delete': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'Objects=[{Key=2019-03-27T160001Z.tar},{Key=2019-03-27T170001Z.tar}]'`

Comment: It worked on a Mac. If you are using Windows, try dropping the single quotes.